# Am I interpreting this pseudocode wrong?

Tags: c++, algorithm, array-algorithms

I've got this pseudocode:

```
COMPARE-EXCHANGE(A,i,j)
    if A[i] > A[j]
        exchange A[i] with A[j]

INSERTION-SORT(A)
    for j = 2 to A.length
        for i = j-1 downto 1
            COMPARE-EXCHANGE(A,i,i+1)
```

I would interpret it as:

```
void insertSort( )
{
    int tmp;

    for( int j = 2 ; j < MAX ; ++j )
    {
        for( int i = j - 1 ; i > 0 ; --i )
        {
            if( unsortedArr[i] > unsortedArr[i + 1] )
            {
                tmp                 = unsortedArr[i];
                unsortedArr[i]      = unsortedArr[i + 1];
                unsortedArr[i + 1]  = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However that would skip `unsortedArr[0]`.
Which means it won't work.

Changing the 2nd `for` to:

```
for( int i = j - 1 ; i >= 0 ; --i )
```

Will make it run as intended.
Is there a mistake in the pseudocode or was my first try of interpreting it wrong?

Comment: It is likely that the pseudocode uses 1-indexed arrays, whereas in C++ arrays are 0-indexed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> However that would skip unsortedArr[0]. Which means it won't work.

It is nearly universal for pseudocode to number array elements from 1, not from zero, as in C/C++

> Changing the 2nd for to:
>
> for( int i = j - 1 ; i >= 0 ; --i )
>
> Will make it run as intended.

That is not enough: you also need to start `j` at `1` rather than `2` in the outer loop.

Also note that the C++ standard library offers a `std::swap` function which takes care of exchanging the elements of the array for you:

```
if( unsortedArr[i] > unsortedArr[i + 1] )
{
    std::swap(unsortedArr[i], unsortedArr[i+1]);
}
```

Comment: I didn't think of that appreciate the advice.

Answer (score 3):

I think your pseudo code is assuming that arrays start with index one [1] -- where in C & C++ they start at zero [0].

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing that the pseudocode is using 1-based indexing, rather than the 0-based indexing that C++ uses.